Data compression / time series machine learning
A very generic question, not sure how to express it correctly.
I have a set of 192 sensors.
One measure needs 4 sensors to measure.
So I have about 10k combinations of those 192 sensors say something like
1,2,3,4, val1
2,3,4,5, val2,
....
13,10,1,192, val3.

This will be my dataset 1.
The same 10k combinations of those 192 sensors, measure a different day. This is my dataset 2. Overall I have 2k datasets.
What I look for is for a ML algorithm, that it will be trained from those 2k datasets, find a relation between the 10k combinations, so future measures will only use a subset of the 10k combinations (say data compression).
What kind of ML algorithm can work ?
